# TypeScript Index Signature inhered normal type

Tags: typescript

Why I get an Error with my code? The code without the `sum` property works well.

```js
type IData = {
  [position: string]: {
    [year: number]: {
      [month: string]: {
        val: number
        id: string
        currency: string
      }
      sum: number
    }
  }
}
```

[image: ErrorDialog]
[And why this works?](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/index-signatures#having-both-string-and-number-indexers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your other (non-indexed) keys in the object defined with indexed type must have compatible type with the indexed field.

You may rewrite your type as:

```ts
type IData = {
  [position: string]: {
    [year: number]: {
      [month: string]: {
        val: number
        id: string
        currency: string
      } | number // notice added | number
      sum: number
    }
  }
}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Nn63qN)

to pass typescript rules regarding [indexable types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types).